# How to sort posts based on the value (number) of a post's metadata?

Tags: php, loop, sort

I'm using the [GD Star Rating plugin](http://www.gdstarrating.com/) and the [bbPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bbpress/). The first plugin do have a argument to sort posts by number of votes. But unfortunately, It doesn't work with `WP_Query` (and apparently the **bbPress loop** uses it).

That's why I wanted to create my own way of sorting custom post types in a custom loop.

Let's say I have a function or a variable that outputs the number of votes of each post:

```
<?php votes_number(); ?> or $votes_number
```

How can I use them in something like this:

```
query_posts( "orderby=votes_number" );
```

or

```
query_posts( "my_custom_orderby=votes_number" );
```

Comment: Where is **number of votes** stores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order using post based custom fields you have to store your variable in an actual field using `add_post_meta` or `update_post_meta`, or manually add it to the post field.

That way you can use `WP Query` to query the meta value for that field and order by the value. For example;

```
//adds a value to a field with the key name 'vote_field' and your variable.
<?php add_post_meta($post_id, 'vote_field', $votes_number); ?>

//query the key 'vote_field' and order by
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 
                             'post_type' => 'post', 
                             'meta_key' => 'vote_field', 
                             'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
                             'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

Also there are additonal paramters you can use such as `meta_value_num` and '[meta_compare](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)'

Comment: Hey thanks I think that's exactly what I needed. One more thing, how can I use that to sort posts by including the query in the URL. For instance, www.mysite.com/blog?orderby=meta_value?

Comment: the `orderby=meta_value` needs to know the `meta_key` on order to know where to look.